# MySQL 'YEARWEEK()' off by 1 week

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

When I run: `SELECT YEARWEEK('2018-09-11');` it returns `201836`.

What? It should, of course, be week 37.

I know, there's a setting to tell MySQL what day the week should start on, but that is either Sunday or Monday. This is a Tuesday so that should not matter.

Any thoughts what might be going on? I'm using MariaDB 10.1.32 on a CentOS 7 server.

Comment: "It should, of course, be week 37" - why do you think that? What is your definition of week? `YEARWEEK`, like `WEEK`, has `mode` parameter that defines what "week" is. By default it's `0`, which says that 1st week in 2018 starts on 2018-01-07.

Comment: the time zone, what is it set to of your db? You say it's tuesday, but for some its still monday, check the timezone setting.

Comment: Specifically, `YEARWEEK('2018-09-11')` is equivalent to `YEARWEEK('2018-09-11', 0)` unless you messed with defaults; `YEARWEEK('2018-09-11', 2)` will get you the same result. Any other mode (`1`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`) will give you `201837`.

Comment: OK, so it's about this 'mode' nonsense. I gathered that it had something to do with either the week starting on Sunday or Monday, which makes sense, but apparently it also is about determining the first week. The default of '0' starts the year with 'week 0' until it's Sunday...? How is this useful? Which mode provides the week numbers that we use on basically every calendar on earth?

Comment: "How is this useful?" - for example, to comply with the standard definition of [commercial week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) as defined by International Standardization Organization? Yeah, who needs that. Anyway, refer to the table [in MySQL docs on `WEEK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) to figure out which mode you need. You use it on basically every calendar on earth, it should be trivial.

Comment: 'Commercial week', sounds like something on TV. You like being smart, how about answering the simple question how to get the week number we are all looking at on our calendars.

Comment: You're being combative, defensive and dismissive, but that will not get you to the answer quicker. Let me say it once more. I have no idea what _your_ definition of week is. I don't have week numbers on my calendar. I have never used a week number. I don't need a week number. I am almost positive I don't live in the same country you do, nor am I born in the same country you are, and our calendars are likely different. The only person who knows how to define the week you need is _you_.  Just examine the definitions in the table, and find the one that matches what you expect in your culture.

Comment: Or, if you find the table's definitions too confusing and you can't formulate a definition for what your week is, then go to your calendar with week numbers written on it and read off which date is the start of Week 1 - that would be information enough for us to tell you which `mode` you need to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should see this site for reference: [MySQL YEARWEEK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek)

Accordingly to above, you can specify how weeks should be counted: second argument (optional) tells what is the first day of the week and how many days it should include to be counted, for example:

> 1 - First day of week is Monday and the first week has more than 3 days

You could try this query:

```
SELECT YEARWEEK('2018-09-11')
union all
SELECT YEARWEEK('2018-09-11', 1)
union all
SELECT YEARWEEK('2018-09-11', 3);
```

It returns:

```
201836
201837
201837
```

So, you should have a feeling now how to use `YEARWEEK`.

[Demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/59518)

Comment: Boggles the mind... I'm still looking for the correct 'mode', the one that will give me week numbers like they use on calendars. It could not be '1', because apparently that still starts the year with 'week 0', as noted in the official documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week (I would use this for reference in your answer also).

Comment: The difference between 1 and 3 is whether January days before week 1 are week 0 of this year or week 53 of the previous year. Week 1 starts at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the *mode* flag correctly depending on how you define the first week of the year

```
SELECT YEARWEEK('2018-09-12',0); -- 201836
SELECT YEARWEEK('2018-09-12',1); -- 201837
SELECT YEARWEEK('2018-09-12',2); -- 201836
SELECT YEARWEEK('2018-09-12',3); -- 201837
SELECT YEARWEEK('2018-09-12',4); -- 201837
SELECT YEARWEEK('2018-09-12',5); -- 201837
SELECT YEARWEEK('2018-09-12',6); -- 201837
SELECT YEARWEEK('2018-09-12',7); -- 201837
```

See the [MySql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)

Comment: That pattern looks strange.

Comment: @RickJames What pattern? Could you clarify?

Comment: results: 67677777 -- I would expect some 6s, then some 7s.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the default setting is using the [0] mode option (SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'default_week_format'), meaning the Sunday is taken into consideration. Means also 2018-09-08 which returns the 36. In Order to get the next week start with monday, mode [1].